# pytorch CUDA version vs. Nvidia CUDA version

Tags: python, pytorch, cuda, conda

Till Apr26th, 2022, CUDA has updated to version **11.6**, which can be installed by **[Nvidia Instruction](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=runfile_local)**:

```sh
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.6.2/local_installers/cuda_11.6.2_510.47.03_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.6.2_510.47.03_linux.run
```

I guess the version of `cudatoolkit` will also be **11.6**

However, there is no version of `pytorch` that matches `CUDA11.6`.

On the website of **[pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)**, the newest `CUDA` version is **11.3**, `pytorch` version will be **1.11.0(stable)**

```sh
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

So if I used **CUDA11.6** and **pytorch1.11.0** with `cudatoolkit=11.3`, will it perform normally?
and if there is any difference between `Nvidia Instruction` and `conda method` below?

```sh
conda install cuda -c nvidia
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fine. Otherwise, I saw [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-cuda-11-6/149647?msclkid=c2583970d11e11ec86bcfa653276ea6f) that you can build it from the source (I have python=3.8.13) [build instructions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source)

```
pip install torch --pre --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu116
```